# How to access the element at variable index of a tuple?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a function to read vectors from stdin, and here is what I have so far:

```
fn read_vector() -> (i64, i64, i64) {
    let mut vec = (0, 0, 0);
    let mut value = String::new();

    for i in 0..3 {
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut value).expect("Failed to read line");
        vec.i = value.trim().parse().expect("Failed to read number!"); // error!
    }
}
```

However, the annotated line contains an error:

```
error: no field `i` on type `({integer}, {integer}, {integer})`
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
13 |         vec.i = value.trim().parse().expect("Failed to read number!");
   |             ^
```

Reading the documentation [entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html) doesn't reveal any `get`, or similar function.

So, is there any way to get the `i`th value of a tuple?

Comment: See also [Reasons for Dot Notation for Tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32030756/155423)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There isn't a way built in the language, because variable indexing on a **heterogeneous** type like a `tuple` makes it *impossible* for the compiler to infer the type of the expression.

You could use a macro that unrolls a `for` loop with variable indexing for a tuple if it is really, *really* necessary though.

If you are going to be using homogeneous tuples that require variable indexing, why not just use a fixed-length array?

Comment: i just got really used to using parenthesis for everything in other languages. which is why i was using tuples instead of arrays. honestly it is just that simple. it helps having clear explanations like this, so thanks.

Comment: "You could use a macro that unrolls a for loop with variable indexing for a tuple" - how would one do this? It's possible to [count with a macro](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/blk-counting.html), but [tuple indices must be literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#tuple-index), yet it looks like it's  [impossible to evaluate expressions in a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576878/how-do-i-evaluate-expressions-in-rusts-macro-system), let alone compute an expression into a literal...

Comment: @ForceBru I should have been more clear, but this can best be achieved by writing a [function-like procedural macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#function-like-procedural-macros). As you mentioned, this would be pretty difficult to do via a conventional macro by example.

Answer (score 9):

> So, is there any way to get the ith value of vec?

No, there isn't. Since tuples can contain elements of different types, an expression like this wouldn't have a statically-known type in general.

You could consider using an array instead of a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

While there are no built-in methods to extract the *i*-th value for non-constant *i*, there exist crates like [`tuple`](https://crates.io/crates/tuple) to implement [dynamic indexing](https://docs.rs/tuple/0.1.5/tuple/#indexing) of a **homogeneous** tuple.

```
extern crate tuple;

...
*vec.get_mut(i).unwrap() = value.trim().parse().expect("!");
```

(But, as [@fjh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43177901/224671) mentioned, it is far better to operate on an array `[i64; 3]` instead of a tuple `(i64, i64, i64)`.)